# Nissan Juke 2017 plate ... battery

Tags: battery, nissan, ignition, juke

My father-in-law was looking after my 17 plate juke while I’m travelling, he let battery die . He recharged battery but now ignition won’t turn off and car will not lock

Comment: First, is it keyed or push button? Then, is the key moving back from the "start" position to the "on" position? If the key, ignition switch, or relay are staying in the "start" position that will cut most of the accessory circuits, presumably including power lock, windows, etc.

Comment: What is a "plate?" Or, perhaps, what does "plate" mean?

Comment: It is keyless ... and what I ment by plate is it is a 2017 model

Comment: What is the question? If the battery does not take a charge, then replace the battery.